# Oracle Apex application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

We are doing a project on Oracle Apex for university. We have 12 tables and try to build an app for our project. When we try to add a new page for some of our tables (not all of them) we encounter this error [error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDjQv.png).

Can someone know how to solve this issue which is really blocking us right now.

We tried everything to solve it. All of our constraints in our tables work. What we don't understand is why we can create sometimes new pages from some tables but for other it does not work.

Comment: Unrelated comment: from your screenshot it seems that the table names are case sensitive. As a general rule in oracle database development (therefor - APEX development as well): avoid that. Stick to upper case for tables/columns. This should not have to do with the error though

Answer (score 0):

To me, that (unfortunately) looks like bug as you don't have any impact on Apex' data dictionary tables.

If you connect as a privileged user and check what's exactly being violated, you'll see something like this.

Which table is that constraint related to? Apparently, none:

```
SQL> select table_name from dba_constraints where owner = 'APEX_200200' and constraint_name = 'WWV_DICTIONARY_CACHE_OBJ_IDX2';

no rows selected
```

Any luck with (unique) indexes, then? Yes!

```
SQL> select table_name from dba_indexes where owner = 'APEX_200200' and index_name = 'WWV_DICTIONARY_CACHE_OBJ_IDX2';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
WWV_DICTIONARY_CACHE_OBJ
```

Which columns are used to enforce uniqueness?

```
SQL> select column_name from dba_ind_columns where index_name = 'WWV_DICTIONARY_CACHE_OBJ_IDX2';

COLUMN_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SECURITY_GROUP_ID
OBJECT_ID
OBJECT_TYPE

SQL>
```

That's to get you started; you know which table you used for that page so write some more queries and you'll - hopefully - find some move info.

How to "fix" that error? I hope you won't delete or update anything on Apex' dictionary tables! Maybe you'd rather **rename** that table (to avoid uniqueness violation) and try to use it, with its new name, while creating the page in your application.

Answer (score 0):

> If a workspace contains other object types with the same name as a table, APEX data dictionary cache job, ORACLE_APEX_DICTIONARY_CACHE, fails with ORA-00001: UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (APEX_190200.WWV_DICTIONARY_CACHE_OBJ_IDX1)
> Workaround: Remove the duplicate object that is not a table. You can list database objects by selecting from sys.dba_objects.

[Oracle APEX 19.2 Known Issues](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/apex-downloads/apex-192-known-issues.html)